# "How to solve a system of equations of estimators (alpha and beta) using the method of maximum likelihood (beta distribution) in R?"

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, beta-function

```
set.seed(42)
# Data
x <- rbeta(100, 4.0, 2.0)

logLikGrad <- function(params){
 a <- params[1]
 b <- params[2]
 
 grad_a <- (digamma(a+b)) - (digamma(a)) + sum(log(x))
 grad_b <- (digamma(a+b)) - (digamma(b)) + sum(log(1-x))
 
 
 c(-grad_a, -grad_b)
}


startParams <- c(4, 2)


fit <- nleqslv(startParams, logLikGrad)


fit$x
```

Hello, I'm encountering an issue with my code. It's yielding negative values that are far from correct. I've searched online and even consulted ChatGPT, but haven't found a solution to my problem. Could anyone help? The task was to derive estimators for the parameters α and β using the method of maximum likelihood (ML) and solve it, implementing it in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a one significant issue plus a minor point, your code works.

The minor point is that if you want other people to reproduce your results then you need to specify what packages you are using, here `nleqslv`

The significant issue is that you started with a likelihood of $$\prod_i \left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x_i^{\alpha-1}(1-x_i)^{\beta-1}\right) = \left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\right)^n\left(\prod_i x_i\right)^{\alpha-1}\left(\prod_i (1-x_i)\right)^{\beta-1}$$ but, in finding the log-likelihood and its derivatives, you lost the $n$ term.  You need to include it.

So if your code looked something like

```
library(nleqslv)
set.seed(42)
# Data
x <- rbeta(100, 4.0, 2.0)

logLikGrad <- function(params){
 a <- params[1]
 b <- params[2]
 
 grad_a <- length(x) * (digamma(a+b) - digamma(a)) + sum(log(x))
 grad_b <- length(x) * (digamma(a+b) - digamma(b)) + sum(log(1-x))
 
 
 c(-grad_a, -grad_b)
}

startParams <- c(4, 2)


fit <- nleqslv(startParams, logLikGrad)


fit$x
```

then it would give the results `[1] 3.828875 1.992556` which are not far from the original values of $4$ and $2$.

Comment: It would be better to start with arbitrary parameters such as `startParams <- c(1, 1)` so you are not seen as prejudicing the calculations, though you would get the same result here. Note that different seeds would give different data and so different estimates.